# Merging Multiple Relations as params

Tags: relatedto, merge

I have the following code where I'm pulling entries related to another entry which works fine. However I also want to limit the entries returned on a category page and thus am merging in a relatedTo: category

However on the category page it is returning all entries related to that category, not limited to the category AND the related entry

```
{% set myStation = getCookie('myStation') %}
{% set relatedStation = craft.entries.id(myStation) %}


{# set pagination/categories #}
{% set params = { section: 'blog', limit: 6, offset: 1, relatedTo: relatedStation } %}
{% if category is defined %}
  {% set params = params | merge({ relatedTo: category }) %}
{% endif %}

{% set entries = craft.entries(params) %}
{% paginate entries as pageInfo, pageEntries %}
```

I see the [docs includes](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/relations.html#the-relatedto-parameter) 'and' (bottom of the page) but I'm not sure how to get that in there using merge. Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
{% set myStation = getCookie('myStation') %}
{% set relatedStation = craft.entries.id(myStation) %}

{% set params = { section: 'blog', limit: 6, offset: 1, relatedTo: relatedStation } %}

{% if category is defined %}
    {% set params = params|merge({relatedTo: ['and',
        { element: relatedStation },
        { element: category }
    ]}) %}
{% endif %}

{% set entries = craft.entries(params) %}
{% paginate entries as pageInfo, pageEntries %}
```

The trick with `merge` is that it will always *replace* matching keys that it finds.  So you need to tell it to replace it with the proper `and` syntax.

Comment: no offense - but did you "solve" the "object could not be converted to an array" error in this case? A few weeks ago I tried your syntax with Craft 3 `['and', category, query, elementId]` and received an exception. I've solved it by doing `['and', ['element': category], [...]]` there was a question here about the same thing because someone else had the same issue

Comment: Seems like it's not the case... As you can see here https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/master/src/elements/db/ElementRelationParamParser.php#L107 the first index will be removed (the "and") and the 2nd index, your `relatedStation` object will be passed to the `subParse` function.. At this point you are trying to merge an array with an object https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/master/src/elements/db/ElementRelationParamParser.php#L143 Sry if this is the wrong place for this.. I'll delete it if that's the case

Comment: No offence at all. :) But I think you're right looking at the code.   Will update the answer and maybe even test it this time.